# Counting checkboxes in JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple line, that I was hoping would count all checked checkboxes with the class (.photos):

```
var count = $('.photos').length;
```

It counts all the checkboxes that have that class (.photos) but it doesn't count the checked ones.

Does anybody know how to alter this line to count the checked checkboxes within this class?

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) pseudo-selector:

```
var count = $(".photos:checked").length;
```

Comment: oh, that easy!! I was try all sorts of things apart from that! Thanks for your time

Comment: Yep, that easy! As with most things in jQuery, there's a nice quick way of doing it. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `:checked` selector, which will only match checked elements.